# Confusion with snprintf and size_t len

Tags: c++, module, printf

sorry for my billionth question but I cannot figure out what is needed for my implementation.

I have this so test file called fmttimetest.cc (contains main) which is part of a module which includes an fmttime.h and fmttime.cc (implementation file)

in fmttime.cc I have this function

```
 28 ExpandedTime* localTime(struct timeval* tv, ExpandedTime* etime)
 29 {
 30     tzset();                                    // Corrects timezone
 31
 32     int epochT = (tv->tv_sec) - timezone;       // Epoch seconds with
 33     int epochUT = tv->tv_usec;                  // Timezone correction
 34
 35     int seconds = epochT % 60;
 36     epochT /= 60;
 37     etime->et_sec = seconds;
 38     etime->et_usec = epochUT;
 39
 40     int minutes = epochT % 60;
 41     epochT /= 60;
 42     etime->et_min = minutes;
 43
 44     int hours = (epochT % 24) + daylight;       // Hours with DST correction
 45     epochT /= 24;
 46     etime->et_hour = hours;
 47
 48
 49     printf("%d,%d,%d\n", seconds, minutes, hours);
 50     printf("%d\n", epochUT);
 51     printf("%d\n", timezone);
 52     printf("%d\n", daylight);
 53     return etime;
 54
 55 }
 56
 57 char* formatTime(struct timeval* tv, char* buf, size_t len)
 58 {
 59
 60 struct ExpandedTime etime2;
 61 localTime(tv, &etime2);
 62 snprintf();
 63 }
```

*note top lines of code which include the structure expanded time are cutoff but i assure you they are implemented properly

Now in my main test file fmttimetest.cc I call the formatTime function. However Im confused on how the buffer and size_t len is suppose to interact. I know to some degree what size_t len is...it gives you the size of an object so to speak. So in my main test.cc I have this

```
  6 #include <curses.h>
  7 #include <sys/time.h>
  8 #include <time.h>
  9 #include "fmttime.h"
 10
 11 struct timeval tv;
 12
 13 int main()
 14 {
 15 char buf[] = {"%d"};
 16 size_t len;
 17 gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
 18 formatTime(&tv, buf, len);
 19 }
```

So heres where im confused. I need to pass this buffer so my implementation program can write to this buffer the epoch time in human readable format e.g Day, Hour, minute, seconds. 
I'm lost as to how I would go about doing this. I cannot change any of the function prototypes they have been given as is and are expected to be used as is......

I am also not sure of how to go about using snprintf() in the context of using it to print the time into the passed buffer....

thanks again for those who read this.

Comment: Don't let size_t confuse you. You can just think of it as you would an unsigned int. It basically lets the compiler choose how big it needs to be to solve portability problems. So keep in mind that you have not set len equal to anything yet.

Comment: I see...am I passing the buffer correctly though? I need to be able to write in it a value for hours minutes milliseconds day month etc...so can i say char buf[] = {%d, %d, %d, %s....} depending on what values need to go into my buffer? or am i just being a complete retard lol

Comment: char buf[] is just an array of characters (a string). The things you should be storing in it are things like 'a', 'b', 'c'. It is not meant to format anything. And think about what it would be like to store a string (%s) at one position in a character array. You'd be trying to set a character equal to a string of characters.

Comment: Hmm i see your point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to call formatTime would be this:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[64];
    size_t len = sizeof(buf);
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    formatTime(&tv, buf, len);
}
```

So you pass in the buffer and its length. The buffer contents are then written by formatTime.

edit: the buffer of course need to have some length that will be enough :)

To use snprintf with your time structure, you could do something like this (untested):

```
snprintf(buf, len, "%02i:%02i:%02i", etime2.et_hour, etime2.et_min, etime2.et_sec);
```

Answer (score 0):

buffer, is a character array. In your case it represents a string.
A string in c is defined as a '\0' terminated character array. the size of the buffer is the length of the string + the  '\0' sign.

let's inspect it further:

```
char buf[] = {"%d"};
size_t len;
len = strlen(buf); // strlen returns the length without the zero terminating char.
len = sizeof(buf); // Because buf is preallocated in compilation, you can get it's length, this includes the zero at the end.
```

Comment: Hmm I understand the definition of an array, itsjust I dont know how to use it in conjuction with snprintf which will print to the buffer. Len needs to be initialized like that? = strlen(buf) and sizeof(buf)?

Comment: Check snprintf documentation, if it adds the terminating zero in to your buffer, or it uses your buffer as the limit for the entire string including the zero